# Create new List<String>() by getting member of List<List<String>>() without linking them

Tags: java, list

I am trying to initialize a `List<String>listBuffer` that is equal to a member of a `List<List<String>>listOfLists`, without linking them. Every time I add to "listBuffer", it automatically adds to that member of the "listOfLists". How do I create a "listBuffer" that is not linked to "listOfLists"?
    //Initial Problem

```java
    List<List<String>>listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    listOfLists.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    List<String>listBuffer = listOfLists.get(0);
    List<String>listBuffer2 = listBuffer;//2ndBufferAttempt
    listBuffer.add("anyString");
    listBuffer2.add("anyString2");
    System.out.println(listOfLists.get(0));
    //Output is [anyString,anyString2]

    //Simple Solution(Not sure whether its the best way)
    List<List<String>>listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    listOfLists.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    List<String>listBuffer = new ArrayList<String>();
    listBuffer.addAll(listOfLists.get(0));
    listBuffer.add("anyString");
    System.out.println(listOfLists.get(0));
```

```
//Output is "[]"
```

I expected the output to be "[]".
The output is instead "[anyString,anyString2]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Parameter list of java.util.Collections.copy() corrected

The `=` does not create a new instance of what type ever, but simply copies a pointer. In your code, `listOfLists.get(0)`, `listBuffer`, and `listBuffer2` point to the same memory area, and so it is not surprising that those are linked together. If you don’t want them being linked, don’t link them. I’s that simple.

```
List<String>listBuffer;
List<String>listBuffer2;
Collections.copy(listBuffer, listOfLists.get(0));
Collections.copy(listBuffer2, listBuffer);//2ndBufferAttempt
```

creates new, independent, unlinked lists; that should do the job.

Comment: [`Collections.copy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy-java.util.List-java.util.List-) takes two parameters. Perhaps you mean a different `Collections` class; if that's the case, specify which.

Comment: That was my mistake, "base" is "listOfLists".

Comment: As it turns out, the [Collections.copy] would require the new list to be the same size as the incoming list which would be annoying. The "addAll" method remains a simpler and shorter solution.

Comment: As it turns out, `Collections.copy()` MAKES the new list to be the same size as the source list. As the destination list contains no elements in this code, `Collections.copy()` does everything that is needed. But you are right. `listBuffer.addAll(listOfLists.get(0))` is a perfect alternative. It works even if `listBuffer` contains already some elements.

Answer (score -1):

Where ever you’re getting base from is linked to listOfLists in some way. Perhaps you could show your `base` declaration for more clarity.

Edit: if you want your other list to be separate, instead of getting it from somewhere else, do something like:

```
List<String> listBuffer = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: This should be in the comments section seeing as it is not an answer

Comment: What do you mean by base declaration? It is "List<List<String>>listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>()" at the top.

Comment: @RobOhRob I don’t have enough rep to comment

Comment: @ryburger you should work on gaining sufficient rep to comment then.

Comment: @QuentinFlattmann In your code you have base.get(0), but we don’t know the value of base.

Comment: @RobOhRob ah, the stackoverflow grind sure is great

Comment: "Base" was supposed to be "listOfLists", my mistake.